# Content Verification in UIAutomation iOS

Tags: ios, testing, automation, appium

I have an application on which I can upload multimedia content(audio, video images) through web interface and can view the content on the iOS app.
I want to know whether it is possible to verify the multimedia content that is uploaded through web interface is actually the same as is visible on the native iOS app. It can be tested manually, but I want to test it automatically.

Currently I'm using Appium for testing the other functionalities of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the multimedia objects is done through MATLAB.
Images can be compared by finding correlation between the images.
Audio can be compared by calculating the spectral features and finding the  eucledian distance between the spectrum of two audios. 
Video can be compared same as the images but you need to extract the frames and than find the correlation.

But as per your need , you want to compare the objects that is uploaded through web interface to what you observing in the your app, for this, you can use MATLAB api in java for accessing the MATLAB functions.

You can store the variables of multimedia object in data base and the generate the same variable of multimedia objects by downloading the files from app and write codes for comparing these variable using MATLAB api's.

Comment: the basic problem I'm having is to download the files. I cannot do that as I have access only to the UI through UIAutomation instruments. This doesn't allow me to download the content, just to view it in UIViews or other containers of the like.

Comment: @Bansal even if you only have access to the UI, can you start the download from your app in any way? How does your app receives the data? In any case, you can write a script to start the download and invoke it from UIA using *performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout*